# How to Create Database Audit Specification for a column?

Tags: sql-server-2008-r2, audit

I am creating SQL Server 2008 R2 Database audit Specification
for tblPerson.SSN

I selected

```
Audit Action Type: Update
Object Class: Object
Object Name: tblPerson
Principal name: Public
```

It captures all changes to the table. How could I see just one column?

I could filter my column out

```
select statement,* from fn_get_audit_file ('q:\SQLBackup\*',null,null) 
where statement like '%SSN%'
```

Comment: If you want to audit changes to just one column, I suggest you use a trigger instead.

Answer (score 2):

I am not sure you can. However it is a bit confusing, MSDN says that it is possible:

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc280645(v=sql.105)

However following the example that they give I get the following error:

> Msg 33211, Level 15, State 1, Line 0
>   A list of subentities, such as columns, cannot be specified for entity-level audits.

The message above seems to be pretty definitive, I have tried their example on 2008, 2008 R2 and 2012 and I get the same message every time.